# MongoDB createIndex() when using populate() in my query

Tags: mongodb

I have a query into my MongoDB database like this:

```
WineUniversal.find({"scoreTotal": {
      "$gte": 50
    }})
    .populate([{
        path: 'userWines',
        model: 'Wine',
        match: {$and: [{mode: {$nin: ['wishlist', 'cellar']}}, {scoreTotal: {$gte: 50}}] }
}])
```

Do I need to create an compound index for this query?

OR

Do I just need a single-item index, and then do a separate index for the other collection I am populating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MongoDB` it is not possible to index across collections, so the most optimal solution would be to create different indexes for both collections you are joining.

PS: You could use `explain` to see the performance of your query and the indexes you add: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/explain/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.explain

Comment: `explain` would not help in this case as `mongoose` executes population as a separate query. I do agree separate indexes are usually~ the way to go, but as mentioned in my answer are probably not relevant here as much.

Answer (score 1):

`mongoose`'s "`populate`" method just executes an additional `find` query behind the scenes into the other collection. it's not all "magically" executed as one query.

Now with this knowledge is very easy to decide what would be optimal.

For the first query you just need to make sure "WineUniversal" has an index for `scoreTotal` field.

For the second "populated" query assuming you use `_id` as the population field (which is standard) this field is already indexed.

`mongoose` creates a condition similar to this:

```
const idsToPopulate = [...object id list from wine matches];
const match = {$and: [{mode: {$nin: ['wishlist', 'cellar']}}, {scoreTotal: {$gte: 50}}] };

match._id = {$in: idsToPopulate}
const userWinesToPopulate = collection.find(match);
```

So as long as you're using `_id` then creating additional indexes could help performance, but in a very very negligible way as the `_id` index does the heavy lifting as it is.

If you're using a different field to populate yes, you should make sure `userWines` collection has a compound index on that field.